# Sublime text 3 throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException while notepad++ does not

Tags: java, notepad++, sublimetext3

Whenever I create a program on sublime text 3 and execute it, a  `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` will occur even if my code is completely correct and can be executed in Notepad++.

For example, a HelloWorld Program:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Java!");
    }
}
```

And just after Notepad++ execute those lines, Sublime text 3 can execute those lines too and no longer throws the `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`.

I really want to use sublime text 3 for its beautiful interface, but this problem is quite annoying. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Quite normal because ... *just after Notepad++ execute those lines* , means that the *source code* has been compiled into `.class`. Also the first `ClassNotFoundException` Suggests exactly that Sublime is not compiling at all , or it compiles the java source into a temp dir and looses the changes , cant really know while you havent shared the actual Sublime issue

Comment: Can you check if sublime text  3 is compiling your Main.java and generating a Main.class file?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have found the solution on the Internet. But still, I would like to find a way to interact with my program in sublime text 3.

Comment: The `sublime-build` that ships with Sublime for Java only calls `javac` on the current file and does nothing else, although there is a default build for `Ant`. Basically, you need something more to do what you want; [Javatar](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Javatar) may help.